# Simple equation for $E_c$

Tags: calculus

Can someone hint me a clue for:
I have the form of  $E_c$=$\frac{mv^2}{2}$ and for p=mv;
I want to have the form for $E_c$ in case when $E_c$ will depend by p. I was thinking to multiply the initial form of $E_c$ with $\frac{m}{m}$ or it is another solution for that?
My final form must be $E_c$=$\frac{p^2}{2m}$.

Comment: that's the usual way to express the kinetic energy in terms of $p$!

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct. Multiply the initial form of $E_c$ by $\frac{m}{m}$ and you get 
$$ E_c=\frac{m^2v^2}{2m} = \frac{p^2}{2m}$$

(of course, there are many other correct ways to derive the same formula).

Answer (score 1):

$$E_c={{m v^2} \over 2}={{(m v) \cdot v} \over 2}={{p \cdot p/m} \over 2}={{p^2} \over {2m}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

$$p=mv$$

Therefore:

$$v=\frac{p}{m}$$

Substitute this in for $v$ and you should get the result you want. The way you did it was more elegant though.